# Why my fprintf function display only one line

Tags: c, file, text

I'm doing exercise about reading character from file then convert to uppercase and writing it down to a file and display the result.
So when I run the program it should display all of my text in my file with upper case 
**but when I run the program it only shows the last line of text (last new line) in uppercase.**
So I check my file and it still contain all of my text with all being upper case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * readFile = NULL;
    FILE * writeFile = NULL;
    readFile = fopen ("original.txt","r");
    writeFile = fopen ("temporary.txt","w");
    char inFile = ' ' ;

    if(readFile == NULL){
        printf("Error opening original file\n\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(writeFile == NULL){
        printf("Error creating temporary file ");
        return -1;
    }

    while ((inFile = fgetc(readFile)) != EOF){
        if (islower(inFile))
        {
            inFile = inFile -32;
        }

        fputc(inFile, writeFile);
    }
    fclose(readFile);
    readFile = NULL;
    fclose(writeFile);
    writeFile = NULL;
    //Rename and Remove
    remove("original.txt");
    rename("temporary.txt","original.txt");
    remove("temporary.txt");
    readFile = fopen("original.txt","r");
    if (readFile == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file 2");
        return -1;
    }
    while ((inFile =fgetc(readFile)) != EOF){
        printf("%c",inFile);
        }
    fclose (readFile);
    readFile = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't declare `inFile` as `char`.  It should be `int`.  Also, your call to `toupper` serves no purpose since you are discarding the return value.  You need to assign it to `inFile`.

Comment: You probably have to `remove("original.txt")` before you can `rename("temporary.txt", "original.txt");`

Comment: Just for the style, but why don't you replace `if(islower(inFile) { inFile = inFile - 32; }` with `inFile = toupper(inFile);` ?

Comment: Sorry I post the wrong code so I updated just now. @TomKarzes Thanks, I'll keep in mind.

Comment: @MichaelBeer I've tried that before and it still doesn't solve the problem so I try some new code from internet.

Comment: @MichaelBeer Sorry I post the wrong code so I updated just now. It's still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Code is absolutely fine. Found No Error in it

Comment: @Vineet1982 So when you run it it's display all text in file properly right?

Comment: @ThanapongSereerat Never said it would solve your issue. In fact, my code is equivalent to yours. I just wanted to help you improve your overall coding quality. If you intend to move on with your skills, you should not just copy some code from the net without understanding what it does. Your `if` statement had me suspect precisely that...

Comment: Apart from that, your code works just like it should with me as well. It creates a new file `temporary.txt` writes all of the contents of `original.txt` to it in upper case and outputs the entire content of that file to the console.

Comment: @Michael, using `toupper()` isn't just a style choice - it's essential for portability.  It does require an unsigned value, making `char` a very poor choice here.

Comment: @TobySpeight That's right. This doesn't matter in here though IMHO, because both code variants use either `toupper` or `isupper`, which both require an `int`. Thus changing back and forth between either of the code variants does not introduce new errors nor solve existing ones...

Comment: @Thanapong, can you reduce to a [mcve] of your problem?  In particular, determine whether it's the transformation or your use of files that's causing a problem.  As it is, there's a lot to wade through that's probably irrelevant.

Comment: Yes Code is absolutely fine working. I don't know which compiler you are using but when i run the code running absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks guys!! I guess I quite understand it now. Thanks for all the advices too.